# Using Car2go Api for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, api, nsfilemanager

Hi I am trying to get the list of all car2go cars and use it for a test application, the only problem is I do not know how to get the information. I have gotten a consumer key and secret key but the problem is I am unsure how to get the file using the api and then once I get the file I don't know how I would read it since it is using xml.

The response from the html is on this site
http://code.google.com/p/car2go/wiki/vehicles_v2_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> once I get the file I don't know how I would read it since it is using xml

You'll need to parse the response to extract the data you want. There are a number of ways to do that. For example, you could use [`NSXMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsxmlparser_class/reference/reference.html) (which is included in Cocoa Touch), or you could use the [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML) library, or you could use [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org).

Comment: would using NSXMLParser be the best choice since it is a library included in xcode?